# Connect Arduino to MySQL database

Tags: android, bluetooth, phpmyadmin, wampserver, arduino-uno

I have a project that needs to make a mobile application, which mainly reads data from a sensor connected to Arduino UNO and show it on the application. So I need to read the data from the Arduino throw Bluetooth and send it to my database server (Wamp/MySQL) in order to read it again by the mobile application.

I actually didn't start real work!! but I need to make sure that this will be the right scenario to go through, i had a trouble finding something helpful that will allow me to connect the Arduino or the Bluetooth to my database server.

So, what I need is a confirmation that this is the right scenario to do, and the second thing is a good resource that will help me to send my data to the database from the Arduino/Bluetooth.

Comment: nitpick: you have a **MYSQL** database. phpmyadmin is a MANAGEMENT INTERFACE for mysql.

Comment: @MarcB I have answered this question and edited the question, would be lovely to get your opinion/comments if there so, thus I always take sample answer for review from user with higher reputation for my own answering improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect your Arduino device directly to database as your questions title. But as you mention it is possible to connect (pair) your Arduino device through Bluetooth device to your Android Phone or other phones.

All sensor data will be send over Bluetooth connection and will be collected by your phone app.

Then your app will send sensor data to your local database environment (like MySQL) or to cloud data store (Like Google Data Store) using RESTful API.

I have just few month back build a full application to do what you are thinking to do.

I suggest you to look at this context awareness framework for inspiration  http://www.awareframework.com. The idea/concept of context awareness is to collect phone and/or external sensor data (like Arduino) and make your device behave automatically depending on data (sensor data) readings.

Here is also a couple of links to connecting Android to MySQL database. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800703/Connecting-your-Android-app-to-your-WAMP-server

Here is also illustration how things are connected:

[image]